# Alternative of AWS SSM for configuration compliance in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, compliance

we want to implement compliance monitoring in our cloud environment. For AWS, we are using AWS SSM to do it. But there is no alternative product in GCP, the only thing that will have the same functionality is cloud security command center and its still in alpha phase. 
Is there any alternative for AWS SSM that can be implemented in GCP? We also want to do it with automation, so more preferable if it has API command. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like [Cloud Checker](https://cloudcheckr.com/) or [Cloud Health](https://www.cloudhealthtech.com/)? I think there are others, but none come to mind right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, The [Google Cloud Security Command Center](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/) is the only alternative to AWS’ SSM. What you could do is deploy any of the Security tools available in the marketplace such as [Qualys](https://www.qualys.com/) or [BeyondTrust](https://www.beyondtrust.com/) but note that these aren't GCP services. They are third party solutions.

If you would like to test an early access of the Cloud Security Command Center, you may fill up the form [in this link](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/commandcenteralpha/) to try out Google Cloud Security Command Center since it is currently in Alpha release.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I use the GCP secrets manager (you can choose to encrypt or not when you create a secret) and it operates similarly to AWS SSM Parameter